# how to find text coordinates in html page

Tags: html

given that tags `margins`, `border`, `padding` can be viewed in chrome inspector is there a methodology to extract word coordination boxes from html **directly**, like the feature found in `pdtotext` when using `--bbox` option
[image: similar to this]

noting that I don't want to convert `html2pdf`, the process should execute on `html` input